# How can I have the integrated VSCode terminal not capture CTRL-E, CTRL-X, and CTRL-A?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I have the integrated VSCode terminal not capture CTRL-E, CTRL-X, and CTRL-A?

Actual behavior: does what the keyboard shortcuts normally do outside of terminal

Expected behavior:

CTRL-X-E should open $EDITOR in the integrated terminal, like it does in Readline-based terminals

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_common-questions

Comment: Thanks, but I looked at those docs, and they don't answer my specific question. It seems that I'd have to work backwards from what terminal actions are bound to the keys currently. I tried and couldn't figure it out after 15 minutes :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per "[Ctrl + e in integrated terminal (bash) when focused brings up command drop down](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27342)" ...

> This is happening because ctrl+e is a default for the
> workbench.action.quickOpen command which is special cased to bypass
> the terminal. To get the behavior you want you will need to remove the
> keybinding by adding this to your keybindings.json:
>
> ```
> { "key": "ctrl+e", "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpen" }
> ```

I tested the above for `Ctrl+e` only on version 1.64.2.

Comment: While I see that this is an official response, I would think that there might be a better way to do this since version 1.12 was released.

Answer (score 13):

From the Command Palette I selected to view the JSON Keyboard Shortcuts, then entered this into the resulting file:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+e",
        "command": "ctrl+e",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
]
```

This allows me to use CTRL+E in the terminal when I have the terminal in focus, rather than it being interpreted by VS Code.

Comment: Did you mean 'ctrl-e'? That worked for me. I can mark your answer as correct after the change, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Done. My intent was to get PSReadLine's history function working, but I guess I didn't answer your question directly. Sorry about that.

Comment: I like this answer because it is so straight forward and almost self-documenting. "When the terminal has focus and I press `ctrl+e`, perform `ctrl+e`." The other answers try to say, "Perform the normal shortcut unless the terminal has focus."

Answer (score 6):

modify vscode `settings.json` to avoid `Ctrl + E` conflict:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
        "-workbench.action.quickOpen"
    ]
}
```

Find other command ID: `Ctrl + K , Ctrl + S` open "Keyboard Shortcuts", press `Alt + K` and then record the conflict key combination.